# Forward Call In Twilio

Tags: function, twilio, twilio-twiml, ivr

I am facing an Issue I want to forward call to an agent if not answered then transfer call to next agent but the issue is I don't have first agent number. I have to make call on Ivr and send keys to connect with agent it is working fine. But Issue is if agent not answered call after 4 rings call to another agent .
Call is not timeout because that is seem to be answered by IVR and when hang-up status is completed
Is there a way to do call forwarding in that way.
Here is the code

```html
const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

   const functionPath = '';

    
   if (event.reason === "dialStatus") {
        console.log(event.DialCallStatus);
     if (event.DialCallStatus === "no-answer" || event.DialCallStatus === "busy" || (event.DialCallStatus === "completed")) {
      
       console.log('Duration'+event.DialCallDuration);
       
        
       return callback(null, twiml);
     } else {  
        console.log(event.DialCallDuration);
       return callback(null, twiml);
     }
   }
   
    var phonenumber=ph.split('-');
   const dialedPartyNumber =ph;

   var digit='www3'
   console.log(dialedPartyNumber);
   console.log(digit);
    const dial = twiml.dial({timeout:`5`, action: `${functionPath}?reason=dialStatus`,hangupOnStar:true });
   dial.number({  sendDigits: digit }, dialedPartyNumber);
    
   
   
    callback(null, twiml);
```

Answer (score 1):

How I've done this before is to put the original call in a conference room. Then call the first agent and ask them to press X to join the conference.  If they do not, then go to the second agent and repeat.

david

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are describing isn't really an issue on Twilio, it's actually a question of state management. From your description, it sounds like you are trying to implement an "inbound queue" solution - where multiple agents are "logged-in" to a queue and will receive calls accordingly.

If what I described is what you are trying to achieve, then a I would recommend trying something like the below:

1. A call comes into your system and queries a remote script for the first agent.
2. The remote script returns a Twiml to route to the relevant agent, with a dial timeout of 8 seconds.
3. The remote script will re-invoked, in case where the call was not answered. When invoked, your server should know that the new invocation is from an existing session - which will respond back with a new agent.
4. Upon answering the call, the answering agent marks the call is answered - making sure step one doesn't return that agent while they are on the phone.

Remember, Twilio (and other CPaaS platforms as well) are asynchronous, which means that you will need to manage your call-routing and call-control states yourself.